# Copy files using a pattern or wildcard

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to copy all files like this:

```
...
dialogue022-en.txt
dialogue023-en.txt
dialogue024-en.txt
...
```

into files like this:

```
...
dialogue022-pivot.txt
dialogue023-pivot.txt
dialogue024-pivot.txt
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform the copy, simply use:

```
for i in dialogue*-en.txt; do cp "$i" "${i/-en.txt}"-pivot.txt;done
```

Or, to see the commands first, use:

```
for i in dialogue*-en.txt; do echo cp "$i" "${i/-en.txt}"-pivot.txt;done
```

The part after the slash simply indicates the string that should be substracted from the original filename.

Kudos to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122605/how-do-i-copy-multiple-files-by-wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions instead with [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) like this:

```
jren "^(dialogue-\d*-)en(\.txt)$" "$1pivot$2"
```

Steps:

1. Copy all the code from [this page's post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081), open notepad and save as jren.txt in the same folder you have those files.
2. Rename jren.txt to jren.bat
3. Open cmd by pressing Windows(Button)+R and type cmd and go to the folder your files are with `cd c:\wheremyfilesare` (or just right click the folder in Windows Explorer while pressing shift and choose to "open command line here")
4. Copy and paste that line above into the command line and voilá!

I got to know JREN through [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279406/1326147) and it works very well.

### Edit

**Warning**: this renames the files, so you should copy them first to another folder if you want to keep both files.
Just in case, if that forum goes offline I placed the [jren code in here for download](https://ideone.com/plain/4GuQXd).